# How to change the default program associated with STL files when option is greyed out (can't take default preference away from SolidWorks)?

Tags: windows-7, file-association, cad, solidworks

I want to have MeshMixer as the default for opening STL files but Windows is not allowing me to switch it from SolidWorks for some reason. When I go into the Default Programs section of the Control Panel, it won't offer the option to "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file". Is there some way I can loosen SolidWorks' grip on this file?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have administrative rights for that user logged in, when  you are trying to do the change?

You have to have admin rights to take this action, login with a different user that has admin rights or assign local admin to the current user